# Defining an imported external module with WebPack + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to get WebPack set up with TypeScript and some external libraries, but having some trouble.

I'm importing the src version of jQuery in order to let WebPack choose the required modules (this was needed to get the Boostrap-SASS loader working), so am importing the library like this in my TS:

```
import jquery = require( 'jquery/src/jquery.js' );
```

When compiling, this throws the error `cannot find external module 'jquery/src/jquery'`. If I create a manual .d.ts file to define the library, like so:

```
declare module "jquery/src/jquery"{}
```

then the compiler works, but warns:

```
cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

Alternatively, if I change the import line to

```
var jquery = require( 'jquery/src/jquery' );
```

(which I think is a CommonJS style import?) then it all compiles (and runs) fine. So, questions:

- Is there a better way of requiring/including the source files using WebPack?
- What's the correct way to define the module so it doesn't lack a call sig?
- Should I be worried about using `var` instead of `import` or just roll with it if it's working?

I've only just picked up WebPack so it's entirely possible I'm doing something stupid. Please correct me if so!

**Edit:**

As I was thinking about how to phrase the question this came to me:

```
declare module "jquery/src/jquery" { export = $; }
```

which seems to let me use "import..." - but is that a good way to handle this?

**Edit 2:**

In reply to @basarat's answer below (my comment got a bit long to be read without line breaks):

I'm already using the jquery def from DefinitelyTyped, but it doesn't work by itself because the module I'm requiring is **"jquery/src/jquery"** and not just **"jquery"**. If I use "jquery" then the compiled dist version of jquery is loaded, which doesn't work with the Bootstrap loader.

So the `declare module "jquery/src/jquery" { export = $; }` is, I think, extending the existing definition but using the path that I need to load it from.

Comment: Tom, I'm wresting with this same issue - I can't seem to find a good source for how to properly include third-party code like jQuery, etc. in a webpack/TypeScript build. Would you be willing to share a little more of your solution?

Comment: @JasonBrubaker I've added my solution as an answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is what I ended up doing.

**NB I don't know if this is the "correct" way of achieving this (I suspect not), so I'm open to anyone with a better answer!**

In my TS definitions file tsd.d.ts I have the Definitely Typed jQuery definition:

```
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

but on its own this wasn't enough for the compiler to pick up the jQuery source files from within the **node_modules** folder.

So further down tsd.d.ts I've added:

```
declare module "jquery/src/jquery"
{
    export = $;
}
```

The compiler can now locate the jQuery source files.

I also had to edit one of the jQuery source files for the WebPack compiler to play nicely with it: **selector.js** doesn't have a factory function included by default, and WebPack requires one to be present.

There's a [loader that says it fixes this](https://github.com/AlexanderOMara/amd-define-factory-patcher-loader) but I couldn't get it to work, so I just changed the code in selector.js to:

```
define([ "./selector-sizzle" ], function(){});
```

This all feels a little bit hacky... but it got me over this particular hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

> import jquery = require( 'jquery/src/jquery.js' );

Use the definitely typed definition for jquery instead : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L3158-L3160 which already allows you to do `import jquery = require('jquery')`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm already using the definition though. I've updated my question with a reply.